# GA4 is blocking main thread in page load

Tags: google-analytics

Just 2 weeks ago our page load speeds started getting crushed with no changes on our end.
[image: Page Experience]

We tested our different tags, and definitely it is our GA4 tag.
[image: Pagespeed Insights]

We tried adding a Timer onto the tag, but it stopped firing altogether. It is currently Async. Anyone else having this problem? Any known solutions?

Comment: Is the screenshot of mobile field data from page speed insights?

Comment: You need to show your workings when you say "definitely our GA4" tag.  Does your browser console show GTM being particularly slow?  What does Google Search Console say the issue is when you click "Open Report"?